# Passing a vector as function parameter

Tags: c++, xcode, function, gcc, vector

In VS 2013 I can do

```
void myFunction(vector<int> myVector)
{
  // Do something with myVector
}
```

And I can use the function with:

```
void anotherFunction()
{
  myFunction({1, 25, 33, 45, 80});
}
```

But if I compile this code with Xcode 3.5 (GCC 4.2) I get the error "*Expected primary expression before '{' token*" and also "*No matching function for call to anotherFunction(void)*".

Is there an elegant workaround I can use to make GCC 4.2 understand that I'm passing a constant vector as a function parameter?

Comment: You need C++11 support for that. GCC 4.2. might offer *some*, but probably not enough for this.

Comment: Much of C++11 is not supported until GCC 4.8 (partial support in 4.7).

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html : no support of C++11 in 4.2.

Comment: Try casting to the type `(vector<int>){1, 25, 33, 45, 80}` - note I'm not really sure this is 100% the correct way to cast a template! But I've seen this error before when initalizing `struct`s the same way!

Comment: @Rich No, that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah fair enough! Just thought I'd mention it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for [initializer lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/) in GCC starts with version 4.4, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). The compiler simply does not understand the syntax.

You need to setup the vector the C++98 way, for example like this:

```
void anotherFunction()
{
  vector<int> myVector;
  const int values[] = {1, 25, 33, 45, 80};
  myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), values, values + sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]));
  myFunction(myVector);
}
```

I don't think you can get much better than that in C++98.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure with GCC 4.2 you'll have to declare the vector beforehand.  Also, I would use a vector<int> const & as a parameter so that it doesn't copy the vector.

Comment: How do you know they don't need a copy of the vector?

Comment: It is worth noting that GCC 4.2 doesn't even accept the initialization of a vector with `vector <int> myVector = { 1, 5, 9 };` that's very annoying because I have to declare and initialize a new const vector everytime I need to call that function.